# Hide Option "Open in Word Online"

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to know is there a way (script) to allow me to hide the option "Open in Word Online" from document menu?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Go to Library Settings > Advanced Settings > Change 'Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents - Open in the client application.

Comment: Thank you.  I have configure that option to open in client application.  I want to know is there a code to hide the option "Open in Word Online" from users.

Comment: Nobody knows how to do this?